# JSON Parse Error Using jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This code fails with an exception indicating invalid JSON:

```
var example = '{ "AKEY": undefined }';
jQuery.parseJSON(example);
```

I was able to fix it by replacing all undefineds with empty strings. Are undefineds not part of JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can wrap your head around this, the *token* `undefined` is actually undefined.

Allow me to elaborate: even though JavaScript has a special primitive value called undefined, `undefined` is **not** a JavaScript keyword nor does it have any special meaning.  You can break code which tests for the existance of an object by comparing to `undefined` by defining it.

```
var obj = { BKEY: 'I exist!' };
if (obj.AKEY == undefined) console.log ('no AKEY');
if (obj.BKEY == undefined) console.log ('should not happen');

undefined='uh oh';

if (obj.AKEY == undefined) console.log ('oops!'); // Logically, we want this to execute, but it will not!
if (obj.BKEY == undefined) console.log ('should not happen');
```

The only console output will be 'no AKEY'.  After we've assigned to the global variable `undefined`, `obj.AKEY == undefined` becomes false because `undefined != 'uh oh'`.  `obj.BKEY == undefined` still returns false, but only because we're lucky.  If I had set `obj.BKEY='uh oh'`, then `obj.BKEY == undefined` would be **true**, *even though it actually exists*!

You probably want to explicity set `AKEY` to `null`. (By the way, `null` **is** a keyword; `null='uh oh'` throws an exception).

You could also simply omit `AKEY` from your JSON, in which case you would find:

```
typeof(example.AKEY) == 'undefined'
```

(If you set `AKEY` to `null`, then `typeof(example.AKEY) == 'object'`.)

The only real difference between setting to null and omitting is whether you want the key to appear in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 4):

No, but `null` is.  RFC 4627 [§2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.1):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array,
> number, or string, or one of    the
> following three literal names:
>
> ```
>   false null true
> ```

```
var example = '{ "AKEY": null }';
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct.  Undefined and functions are not represented in JSON.  http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

They're not permitted in JSON...look at the alternative and it's clear as to why:

```
var example = '{}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(example);
obj.AKEY //undefined
```

If it's `undefined`, when you go to access it, it's the same as the key not even being present.  Since JSON's primary purpose is for transmitting data (otherwise the broader object literal syntax is fine)...it's better to leave it out altogether.

Comment: There *is* a difference between `{}` and `{AKEY: undefined}`.  With the latter, `AKEY` will show up in `for each` enumeration.

Comment: @Matthew - When you're accessing it though, there's no difference...can you think of a valid use case where you'd want to see it enumerated and care, given it's not defined?

Comment: No.  And it definitely simplifies things for JSON just to have null.  I just wanted to note that there is a difference.