# variable named undefined in Javascript Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)
>   [What advantages does using (function(window, document, undefined) { … })(window, document) confer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-window)

i have seen many javascript libraries create a variable named "undefined", iam unable to figure out its purpose, below are lines copied from jQuery library

```
 * Date: Wed Feb 23 13:55:29 2011 -0500
 */
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Use the correct document accordingly with window argument (sandbox)
var document = window.document;
var jQuery = (function() {
```

Please suggest me the reason and benefits of doing so!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you will see is something like this:

```
(function(undefined) {
    /* lots of code */
}());
```

This creates an anonymous function and immediately executes it.  The function has a parameter  called `undefined`.  Since there is no argument passed to the function, the variable `undefined` is in fact the Javascript [primitive value `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

So why do you want to do this?  Well, the problem is that you can actually create a variable with the name `undefined` and set it to anything you like, e.g.:

```
var undefined = 'some text';
```

A test `myvalue === undefined` within your code would then have unexpected results.

The anonymous function with the parameter called `undefined` essentially "resets" the value of `undefined` to the primitive value, so that you can check against it if you wish without having to worry about whether it has the right value.

Answer (score 6):

Its to make sure `undefined` is actually `undefined`. [Paul Irish calls it the asshole effect](http://vimeo.com/12529436#t=319), other js included on the page could change the meaning of undefined, and then you will get unexpected results.

Comment: I never quite understood it. I could also do something silly like `jQuery = {}`, and then jQuery would stop working - not surprising. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot by putting `undefined = true`, why stop you?

Comment: Well someone else could try shooting you in the foot, like a random plugin your including.