# What is the purpose of a parameter named "undefined" in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, undefined

While viewing jQuery's uncompressed source code I stumbled upon something I don't quite understand.  When the create their anonymous function, they place undefined as a 2nd argument.  What is this doing, and why are they using undefined?  Is it necessary to put undefined as an argument in an anonymous function?  Below is an example of what I am talking about.

```
(function( window, undefined)  {
  ...code here
})( window );
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5020479/

Comment: Related: [Why is window.undefined mutable in old browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29742135/1048572)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What this is doing, is reassigning `undefined` to `undefined` inside that closure. Thats a failsafe. Because other code may accidentally do something like

```
undefined = something;
console.log(undefined); // will output 'something'
```

And thats valid in javascript(if the JS engine being used has not implemented ECMAScript 5 specification, in ECMAScript 5 spec `undefined` is non `non-writable`, [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) ),

Quote from MDN [New_in_JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5) (ECMA 5) Page

> **Changes to global objects**
>
> **Global objects made read only**
>
> The **NaN**, **Infinity**, and **undefined** global
>   objects have been made **read only**, per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

And from `ES5 Annotated Spec` in Guthub

`ES5 spec Section` [`x15.1.1.3`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.3)

> 15.1.1.3 undefined
>
> The value of undefined is undefined (see 8.1).
>
> This property has the attributes { **[[Writable]]: false**, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

Even if `global undefined` is not writable You can have a local variable named `undefined` and can mess up your code(mainly comparisons with `undefined`). **But that's your responsibility.** You can have codes like

```
(function(){
    console.log('Second Case: ');
    var undefined = 'Something';
    console.log(undefined); // Will log `something`
    var a ; // a is undefined
    console.log(a  ===  undefined); // false, as undefined is changed
    // you might expect a === undefined will return true, but as 
    // `undefined` is changed it will return false.
    console.log(a); // undefined
})();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/V4DKN/

However if `undefined` is writeable then the above assignment may hamper many `comparison` made with `undefined` after that line of code as `undefined` is not `undefined` anymore. It has some value now.

So as they are calling that anonymous function like

```
( window ) // one argument only
```

And receiving

```
( window, undefined)  // only window is passed when calling the function
          // Second argument is not passed means it's undefined
          // so undefined is restored to undefined inside that function
          // and no global accidental assignments can hamper jQuery's 
          // code using 'undefined' now
```

That means inside that closure `undefined` is restored to `undefined`, as it has not been passed any value thus securing use of `undefined` inside that anonymous function.

A very good detailed article on this http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

I am quoting some lines from the above article link to make things clear

**What is undefined?**

In JavaScript there is **Undefined (type)**, **undefined (value)** and **undefined (variable).**

**Undefined (type)** is a built-in JavaScript type.

**undefined (value)** is a primitive and is the sole value of the Undefined type.

Any property that has not been assigned a value, assumes the undefined value. (ECMA 4.3.9 
and 4.3.10).

A function without a return statement, or a function with an empty return statement returns undefined. The value of an unsupplied function argument is undefined.

```
var a;
typeof a; //"undefined"

window.b;

typeof window.b; //"undefined"



var c = (function() {})();

typeof c; //"undefined"



var d = (function(e) {return e})();

typeof d; //"undefined"
```

**undefined (variable)** is a global property whose initial value is undefined (value), Since its a global property we can also access it as a variable. For consistency I’m always going to call it a variable in this article.

```
typeof undefined; //"undefined"
var f = 2;
f = undefined; //re-assigning to undefined (variable)
typeof f; //"undefined"
```

As of ECMA 3, its value can be reassigned :

```
undefined = "washing machine"; //assign a string to undefined (variable)
typeof undefined //"string"
f = undefined;
typeof f; //"string"
f; //"washing machine"
```

Needless to say, re-assigning values to the undefined variable is very bad practice, and in fact its not allowed by ECMA 5.

Comment: console.log(undefined) .. or not?

yep, like that :)

Comment: so, for example if I had "var undefined = 1" outside an anonymous function, and I had an anonymous function that looked like this:  (function( window, undefined ){ })(window);...are you saying that undefined=1 now has a value of undefined?

Comment: @JaPerk14, Check the updated answer, I have quotes some lines from the article, for a `in-depth` understanding I would suggest you to Read that full article.

Comment: @JaPerk14, if you have a `undefined = 1`; in global scope, then if you dont use `(function( window, undefined ){ })(window);` undefined will have a value of `1` inside that function too(as you changed the global `undefined` variable). Which is not desirable, as `undefined` should be `undefined`. So to ensure inside your function that `pattern` is used.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined is a type but is also a global variable.

You can have a module that overwrites the value of undefined by doing `undefined = whatever`.

`undefined` in the is actually an undefined parameter of a function wrapping the whole code:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
    // undefined is the undefined parameter
}(window));
```

It's safe, as the `undefined` parameter is in local scope, and no one except the code in this function can assign to it.

It's not necessary to use `undefined` as parameter when define an anonymous function.

If you see above function you wll notice that it expects **two parameter** but **one** is supplied.

**Why `undefined` need to restored?**

because, to makes sure that `undefined` is indeed `undefined` in the scope between curly braces, even if someone has written something like `undefined = "defined";` in the global scope, because `undefined` can actually be redefined.

**So if you have something like**

```
var undefined = 1;

(function(window, undefined) {
  console.log(undefined); // output will be undefined not 1
}(window));
```

Comment: you don't explain why undefined needs to be restored, the other answers do.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is making sure that `undefined` really is undefined within its scope by not passing an argument to that parameter.

Take this code for example when `undefined` isn't actually undefined:

```
var undefined = 1;
alert(undefined); // 1
```