# Why is window.undefined mutable in old browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser

What was the intent of the team who wrote the specification to make `undefined` mutable and hence not good for comparison?

Comment: A primitive value automatically assigned to variables that have just been declared or to formal arguments for which there are no actual arguments.
Read more at..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: Why does it matter now? Sometimes things just happen because they happen. JavaScript didn't originally have `undefined` at all. It had an `undefined` *type*, but not a `window.undefined` property. Later, the browsers added the `undefined` property, but most likely nobody really thought about it a lot.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Just curious. So you're saying that there was no expectation of people mutating `window.undefined`?

Comment: i personally think it's still good for comparison. if someone wants to break JS, they will. There's a million other things we can guard against that we don't, why does this one get all the press?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel - @Bubbles's answer gives some great insight into this, especially this key point: "There was no mechanism in the original language to even make a property on the window immutable." It wasn't that somebody thought it would be a good idea for `window.undefined` to be mutable, there just wasn't a convenient way at the time to do it any other way. Note in particular that `window.undefined` was not part of the core JavaScript language, just something that a browser vendor added on the browser side of things (as opposed to the JavaScript language itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a singular, definitive answer on this, but here's a look a some of the language design concerns which provide a partial explanation of the mechanics & considerations at play here.

First and foremost: comparable values like `null`, `true` and `false` are [reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). These are fundamental parts of the JavaScript language - on a similar level to `if` and `for`. `undefined` seems an awful lot like `null`, so it's reasonably intuitive to think they'd be the same in terms of usage. It ends up being a bit different - more like `NaN` in this particular regard.

When asking this question, it's worth asking just how much is, in fact, mutable. Practically everything - if you want to override any standard constructor or function, you probably can. `Array`, `Math`, `eval` etc can all be set.

There was no mechanism in the original language to even make a property on the window immutable. Even if the designer thought it would be a good idea to prevent changes to `undefined` there was as of yet no means to do so other than changing its syntactic meaning within the language.

These days though, the core language specification offers much more control over how and why a variable can be changed. ECMAScript 5 added in ways to control how properties are mutable, and whether or not a variable is `writable` can be configured. This can be seen via the [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) function. I believe the only non-writable values on window which might be considered "core JavaScript" are `undefined`, `Infinity` and `NaN` (other values are non-writable in a browser, but I believe they are almost all related to the browser itself, and are not fundamental to the language). [Section 15.1.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) of the specification has the details on this; I could find nothing similar in the [original spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf).

This still doesn't prevent you entirely from "overriding undefined" - if you're not in the global scope, you can treat it as a variable. So, this will simply print `undefined` when executed in the global scope -

```
var undefined = 5;
console.log(undefined);
```

But this will print 5 -

```
(function() {
    var undefined = 5;
    console.log(undefined);
})();
```

This doesn't change the value at all, it just creates a new local reference to a variable called "undefined". Since the value is defined on the top-level scope (`window`), the language only prevents assignment to that specific property on that one specific object.