# Immutable undefined in self invoking functions

Tags: javascript, performance, security, ecmascript-5

It's been a while since ECMAScript 5 came out and is being [supported quite well](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) in most modern browsers (IE9, CH 19+, FF 4+) and with it so is the "Immutable undefined". Though I keep seeing "undefined" being passed like so:

```
(function ( ..., undefined ) {

})(...);
```

From what I can tell [Crockford's JSLint tool](http://www.jslint.com/) doesn't really like it:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'undefined' (a reserved word).
```

Even though it's not being passed (there's no argument on the function call) and it's really an identifier. I understand that his tool [isn't a bible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo) we should follow to the death and on the other hand [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) doesn't seem to care about it.

Is this still considered a best practice today and how does it affect code performance/security? Considering browser support >= IE9.

Comment: @bfavaretto no, It is immutable everywhere most modern browsers `undefined = 1; undefined; // undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this still considered a best practice today and how does it affect code performance/security? Considering browser support >= IE9.

Much like [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) is a non-writable property of the global object rather than a literal like [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), so it can be used as a parameter name without raising an error. Lets consider a function like this

```
function example(Infinity) {
    return Infinity;
}
```

In `example`, `Infinity` is no longer a non-writable property and instead acts like any other parameter to a *function*, initialised as `undefined` if nothing is passed or otherwise taking the value of the argument. This means in this *function* you can't just assume `Infinity` will mean *Infinity*, because it doesn't, but you could assume it will mean `undefined`.

So let's go back to the question of `undefined`. It will be initialised as `undefined` so the meaning will stay the same, however, it has now lost it's immutability within the function and therefore any typos assinging a values to `undefined` will have this error carried forward. Additionally, if a parameter is passed to the function the value will be different from the start.

Therefore to conclude, it does have an effect on security, as an `undefined` like this is no longer as "safe" because it has lost it's immutable status and can be changed.

---

It may be interesting to note that `undefined` is not actually a [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) [word](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1). If you require an `undefined` for compatibility, rather than adding it as a parameter name, I would suggest using a simple `var undefined;` at the top of the function [or in the global namespace where you will find `var undefined; undefined = 1; undefined; // undefined`](http://jsbin.com/ekejuj/1/edit) where it is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to comply with [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/), you could use another variable that is not a reserved word instead of `undefined`. The following complies with [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/):

```
(function (window, document, undef) {
    'use strict';

}(window, document));
```

You would, however, need to remember to use your newly defined variable (in this case `undef` instead of `undefined`). *The strict mode above was added to comply with jsLint.* **This is mostly used so that you know for certain that the variable you are testing to be undefined is actually undefined.**

Note, that if you're running this example in the text area provided on the  [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) website, you may need to define `window` and `document`. I was receiving two errors until I did so.

```
var window = window; //global window object
var document = document; //global window object
```

**However,** I'm of the opinion that:

```
(function (..., undefined) {
    'use strict';

}(...));
```

is perfectly fine and more importantly, highly recommended.

There are cases where reserved words can be changed from their normal states. Such as setting `undefined` to `true`. Paul Irish discusses this briefly in his video: http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

Comment: In Firefox, `(function (undefined) { 'use strict'; alert(undefined); })(1);` alerts `1`. It seems like strict mode does not disallow the function parameter from monopolizing `undefined`.

Comment: The `strict mode` above was added to comply with jsLint. Your example above works exactly as to be expected. However, since you are the one programming and wrapping your code in the anonymous self-executing function, why would you knowingly do so?

Comment: Aha, I was just about to clarify my question. I didn't understand that your recommendation to use strict mode was validation-oriented; now I get it.

Comment: I can see how that may have been a bit unclear. I'll add a bit more clarification.