# When to use global variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I need to set the `dateFormat` for a few datepickers.

What is the best way to define the `dateFormat`?

Defining a simple method like

```js
function dateFormat() {
    return 'yy-mm-dd';
}
```

or Global variable like

```js
dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd'
```

?

Comment: There's no advantage in the first one.

Comment: Well there could be. For example if it's depending on the users geolocation, the users choice or something similair.

Comment: The _function variant_ would cost you an extra function call. The difference is hardly measurable. The answer to your question also depends on how you designed your backend code.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann, Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me out when to use global variables in jquery with an example if any?

Comment: @SivaKrishnaAytha Posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195120/when-to-use-global-variable-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment26676457_18195120):

> @MarkusHofmann, Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me out when to use global variables in jquery with an example if any?

…I've been looking for information about the use of *global variables* with *jQuery*.

Here I'll sum up what I've found. You may find the sources at the end of this answer.

#### Here we go:

Normally you define global variables by just omitting `var` *(like you did in your question)*:

```
dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
```

***BUT!!!*** Omitting `var` generates an implicit global, which is a bad thing to do and would generate an error in strict mode.

However, if you need to generate global variables in production code *(which should be avoided)* always declare them explicitly:

```
window.dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
```

You can use the above approach to create *global vars* inside a namespace in the window / jQuery object:

*Window Object:*

```
window.myNameSpace = {
    dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd',
    ...
};
```

*jQuery Object:*

```
$.myNameSpace = {
    dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd',
    ...
};
```

But keep in mind to be careful with *naming* the namespace, as there may occur naming conflicts if there is another equal namespace form a plugin or so. I'd recommend to encapsulate the globals within a single global namespace as this makes it independent of jQuery and it doesn't clutter its namespace.

*Encapsulate the globals within a single global namespace:*

```
var MyNameSpace = {}; // The global object container
MyNameSpace.dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd';
```

You may also use a [Closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) to define globals or [Private Member Variables](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

To make this long story short: **It is a best practice to *avoid* globals**.

#### Sources:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352033/2493918
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895772/2493918
3. [How to cleanly deal with global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5063878/2493918)
4. http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace
5. http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/
6. http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html
7. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=namespace+javascript+global

---

### Edit:

**I'd like to add one more thing to my answer:** When I write plugins for jQuery I put all code inside of an [**Immediately Invoked Function Expression** (IIFE)](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression) and then pass the function *jQuery*, and name the parameter *$*. This closure allows you to have your own private variables and protects the jQuery `$` alias:

```
(function( $ ){

    ...YOUR CODE HERE...

})( jQuery );
```

**Ben Alman** has [*a good post*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) on his site that provides more information about IIFE.

There's also a IIFE related question with great answers worth reading here on StackOverflow:
[Using 'window', 'document' and 'undefined' as arguments in anonymous function that wraps a jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15777519/2493918)