# JavaScript: how to protect from "undefined" is defined confusion?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript `undefined` is not a keyword, it is a variable. Sort of special variable. This is known to cause trouble because `undefined` could be reassigned. I do not really know why would anyone want to do that, but this is possible, and maybe you can experience this by using one of those genius frameworks out there, see the code:

```
function f() {
    var z, undefined = 42
    console.log(z, undefined, z == undefined)
} f()
```

**Outputs:**

```
undefined 42 false
```

Now how does one protect himself from such a confusion? Should one just cross his fingers that `undefined` is undefined?

Comment: What normal javascript developer would ever use `undefined` as a variable name? If someone does, then he deserves to be bitten and read/learn more about the language he is using.

Comment: This kind of situation was covered in this (humorous) [talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). More seriously, since JavaScript has only fairly recently become standardized, it has lots of little quirks.

Comment: @Givi, what do you mean?

Comment: @EladStern: JavaScript was standardized **at least** 16-17 years ago, in the form of the ECMAScript First Edition specification in 1997. The third edition spec was released 14-15 years ago in 1999. Granted it's taken some implementations a long time to finally get it right, and the fifth edition (there was no fourth) is only three years old or so.

Comment: Look at [What advantages does using (function(window, document, undefined) { … })(window, document) confer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo) or [How does this JavaScript/JQuery Syntax work: (function( window, undefined ) { })(window)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

Comment: *"JavaScript: how to protect from “undefined” is defined confusion?"* I find taking anyone who redefines `undefined` out to the back and administering a really good beating generally does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `void 0`, it's simply bulletproof. And it's a keyword too.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass undefined as a function parameter, this will ensure that `undefined` is `undefined` in the  scope of the function.

Many JavaScript libraries use this technique, for example look at jQuery source code

```
//jQuery
(function( window, undefined ) {
...
})( window );
```

Because the function expects two formal parameters, but we only give it one, the other gets the (true) value `undefined`, and then we can rely on that within the function.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is to check the type of the variable instead of checking equality to `undefied`:

```
if (typeof(VARIABLE) != "undefined")
```

or read on here: [How to check for “undefined” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript).

Comment: @exebook `typeof x EQ CONSTANT_STRING` is a pattern specifically optimized for - there is no string comparison unless you deviate from the pattern. That means that it's much more efficient to write `typeof x === "string" || typeof x === "number"` because those don't deviate from the pattern whereas saving it to a variable would...

Comment: @exebook: Worry about it ***if and when*** it's a problem.

Comment: @ sailingthoms: `typeof` is not a function, there's no reason to wrap its operand in parentheses. It makes no more sense than `a = (1) + (5);`.

Comment: yes, but I think it helps in getting the point, even if it's not neccesary to use parentheses