# Node.js JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I see a piece of JavaScript code in my Node.js application.

```
( function() { console.log("gg") } )(this)
```

I would like to know why use => ( function(){} )(this) this type of structure, and how does this compile.

I am understanding why we have this two brackets ()(), and why this code would work.

Comment: Ok, the interesting thing is though, why `(this)` is passed?!?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a self invoking anonymous function. This pattern is useful  when you want to hide variables from the global namespace.

```
(function(){
    var foo = "foo";
})();

console.log(window.foo); // undefined
```

Also see [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-m)

[What advantages does using (function(window, document, undefined) { … })(window, document) confer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo)

Comment: How about (function(){})(this); Does "this" invoke this function? How about (function(global, requirejs, require){})(this, requirejs, require) ?

Comment: these are just additional parameters which you can pass to the given function
I'll fix this in my answer

Comment: i think this explains everything you need to know [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo)