# Difference between (function(window){}) and (function(){})

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the following two  code snippets ? I've seen both used in module patters, closures and higher level function declaration. What it the proper use for both ?

```
(function(){


})();



(function(window){


})(window);
```

Comment: I don't think they'd behave any differently. But I don't think it's a good idea to have a variable (or function parameter) with the same name as a built-in object like `window`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo

Comment: Normally you do it like `(function(w){ })(window);` so you have a different variable to reference. You will see this in some minimzer scripts. If you do jQuery development, you are supposed to follow the pattern for plugins. `(function($){ })(jQuery);` Why? because of noConflict mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantic difference is small in this case. However, if `window` is used a lot throughout the code, aliasing it as a local variable allows for better minification.

```
(function (window) { window['foo'] = window['baz']; })(window);
```

can be minified to

```
(function(w){w['foo']=w['baz']})(window)
```

Without the local alias, `window` could not be reduced and the minification would instead be

```
(function(){window['foo']=window['baz']})()
```

There are other reasons as well as other use-cases for similar tricks. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined) question to find more in-depth explanations.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(window){
})(window);
```

1. Now when you pass window `(window);` here, this is the window object, global one.
2. This is a local copy of the window created for that function.

   `(function(window){`
   `})`
3. when you do this ,

   `(function(window){`
   `console.log(window.x)`
   `})`

   you are refering to the local copy not the global one, but still they only hold the reference to the global window object, so eventually you are still accessing the default window object.

So there is no change in behavior, but window object is locally copied.