# How many globals make sense to be passed to the IIFE wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify, uglifyjs, yui-compressor

To which extent does it make sense to pass plenty of global values to an IIFE?

The common thing is just to pass 3 as far as I see everywhere (window, document and undefined).
But... would it make sense to pass more if they are used more than 10 times in the code just for the fact of minification?

In my case I found the global variable `Math` 14 times in the code. It would make sense to pass it to an IIFE in order to save 42 bytes. Which in this case is not a lot, but if we sum bit by bit different global variables, then it would always make sense to pass as many global variables as possible, right? (Symbol, Object, Error, Date, JSON...)

```
(function($, window, document, Math, undefined) {
    $.fn.mydemo = function() {

    };
}(jQuery, window, document, Math));
```

Then, why isn't this a common approach?

### Update:

To explain the 42 bytes of reduction:

- Math = 4 characteres
- 1 character = 1 byte
- 14 times Math = 56 bytes
- Math will get replaced by a single character after minification
- As the function can be defined as function($, w, d, m, u)
- 14 characters of the shorten word Math (m) = 14 bytes
- 56 - 14 = 42 bytes of reduction

Comment: Passing `Math` does not constitute passing an IIFE; it's just a reference to an object.

Comment: Also I'm not sure I see how passing the global `Math` (or anything else) saves memory. Where did you get the value `42`?

Comment: I could be missing something, but I think the only reasons to do this are to use globals under a different name or to get the actual value `undefined`.

Comment: You are not passing "an IIFE", or anything "as IIFE", but you pass objects *to* an IIFE!

Comment: @Bergi right :). Updated.

Comment: @jgillich its quite useful to minify files.

Comment: @Pointy because they will get converted to a single character inside the function, as this can be defined as `function($, w, d, m, u)`

Comment: @Alvaro The difference in file size will be so small, I wouldn't bother. It's not even close to being worth the additional effort during development.

Comment: @Alvaro: `function($,w,d,m,u)` if at all :-)

Comment: What is this *IIFE*?

Comment: @cpburnz: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @jgillich there's no additional development cost. Minifiers will shorthen them when IIFE is used. Not otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it make sense to pass more if they are used more than 10 times in the code just for the fact of minification?

If you care that much about minification, sure, why not?

> The common thing is just to pass 3 as far as I see everywhere (`window`, `document` and `undefined`)

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020479/1048572), altough you see not passing `document`, or passing `jQuery` (aliased as `$`), just as often. And of course it's not only about minification, but [about performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1048572), and you only care for `window` and `document` on that behalf.

> it would always make sense to pass as many global variables as possible, right?

Well, except you don't use them in your code. `Symbol`, `Object`, `Error`, `Date`, `JSON`, `Math` and the others are not needed *that* often in most code. And developers don't like to do those byte counts you are suggesting every time they change a bit of code, so this IEFE boilerplate just stays as it is (and imho there's much cargo cult to it).

You would let your minifier do this automatically if you'd really care.

Comment: Just to clarify it. Minifiers don't compress global variables unless the IIFE is  used. That's why I'm interested on it. I will still using the real name of the variable inside my code.

Comment: @Alvaro: Advanced minifiers *can* automatically detect those and introduce the IIFE by themselves. Not sure if any current implementation does this, but it's possible. I would suggest using your time better than hand-optimising minification results :-)

Comment: Not sure if you understood me. I'm not going to `hand-optimise` anything. The minifiers will do it for me whenever I use the IIFE. And not otherwise.

Comment: You were hand-counting the bytes that are safed by putting `Math` on the IIFE parameters. Isn't that enough evidence? ;-P Putting "everything" there will not be helpful, and deciding what to put there manually seems to be too much work to me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, those values are not IIFEs.

And this is not about “saving characters” by having shorter variables names inside the function (at least not mainly), but rather about variable lookup and the “cost” associated with it.

If you were to use f.e. `document` inside your function without passing it in, then first a variable named `document` would be searched in the scope of the function, and only when that fails, search would continue in the scope above that, and so on.

*That* is the reason for passing such objects as parameters into the function – so that a *direct* reference to them within the function scope exists, and they do not have to be looked up in higher outside scopes.

Sometimes, you might even see this used in such a form like this:

```
(function(document) {
  // do something with document, such as:
  document.foo();
  document.bar = "baz";
})(document);
```

– in that form, it should be even more clear that this is not about saving characters in variable names. The object is still referred to as `document` inside the function (which makes it clear what it is supposed to represent – the *global* `document` object), and the *only* effect achieved by this is said shorter lookup.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the info @CBroe :) 
And, answering my question. Would it then make sense to pass as many as possible when used multiple times inside the function ?

Comment: Well, this lookup isn’t that massively costly under normal circumstances, that this would be anything but micro optimization. If you had a method nested X levels deep inside an object structure, then for large enough X this might start to yield an effect on a fraction-of-a-microsecond level …

Comment: But in reality, this is more or less the same as using `++i` rather than `i++` for the third part of a `for` loop for increasing the counter variable – “faster” in theory, but rather irrelevant in everyday practice. Plus, modern browsers optimize JS code on their own before executing it, so the real-world benefits will be even less substantial.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of cases where it makes sense to pass variables to an IIFE.

### Aliasing

Passing a variable to an IIFE allows you to rename the variable within the function. This is commonly seen when using jQuery, particularly when `noConflict` is used:

```
(function ($) {
   //in here $ will be the same as jQuery
}(jQuery));
```

Aliasing also helps minifiers to minify code, when you see something like:

```
(function (document, slice, Math) {
    ...
}(document, Array.prototype.slice, Math));
```

The minifier can rename the parameters to whatever it wants, and save you bytes. For large scripts using these properties a lot, it can be significant savings when it gets turned into:

```
(function(a,b,c){...}(document,Array.prototype.slice,Math));
```

### Portability

This is more of an edge case than a general rule, but it's common to see a global IIF in the form of:

```
(function (global /* or window */) {
    ...
}(this));
```

This allows for portability between node.js and the browser so that the global variable has the same name in both environments.

### Character Savings

While I already mentioned that minifiers can reduce the character count by changing the names of aliases, you may want to do this manually if you're participating in a [code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript/2714#2714).

### Reference Safety

If you're authoring a script that *must* work in whatever environment its dumped into (think google analytics), you'll want to be sure that the global methods you're calling are what you expect. Storing a reference to those functions by passing them as parameters is one way to preserve the reference to the functions from becoming overridden by a malicious or ignorant programmer.

---

To answer the question in your title:

> How many globals make sense to be passed to the IIFE wrapper?

As many as you need and no more. If you need to alias one or two variables, pass one or two references. If you need to be sure that the global functions aren't being changed, you may end up with 100 parameters. There's no hard-and-fast rule on this.