# return false the same as return?

Tags: javascript

Is

```
return false
```

the same as:

```
return
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No.

`var i = (function() { return; })();`

`i === undefined` which means that `i == false && i == '' && i == null && i == 0 && !i`

`var j = (function() { return false; })();`

`j === false` which means that `j == false && j == '' && j == null && j == 0 && !j`

Weak operators in JS make it seem like the might return the same thing, but they return objects of different types.

Comment: `false != null` on jsbin.com and jsfiddle.net. Are there situations where `false == null`?

Answer (score 39):

No, `return;` is the same as `return undefined;`, which is the same as having a function with no return statement at all.

Comment: Not necessarily.  [Try](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/ZqzH2/) `var undefined='oops'; return undefined;`.

Comment: @josh3736: WTF?  You can name a variable `undefined`.  Who would do that?

Comment: Worse, you could assign the *global* `undefined='oops'`, so that `function() { return undefined; }` would return 'oops'.  Why?  Who knows, but you need to be prepared for the possibility, especially if you're developing a library to be used by other people.  The important thing to realize is that [the token `undefined` is different from the primitive value *undefined*.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225968/json-parse-error-using-jquery-parsejson/4226440#4226440)  (However, ECMAScript 5 does prohibit writing to `undefined`.)

Comment: @josh3736: So, they let you name a variable `undefined`, so you can screw with people?

Comment: @Rocket yes. now sneak `undefined = true` into the jQuery source and watch half the internet collapse.

Comment: @josh3736, @Raynos: There is still a solution to this problem that looks like that: `(function(undefined){/** undefined is really undefined here **/})();` (see [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqVzA/)).

Comment: @Tadeck: You can also do `var undef;` and then use `undef` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Rocket: Good point! It solves the problem with ECMAScript5 mentioned by @josh3736 :)

Comment: @Tadeck: Actaully, he said ECMAScript5 fixes the problem :-P

Answer (score 9):

No.  They are not the same.  Returning `false` from a function returns the boolean `false`, where a void `return` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, one returns `false`, the other `undefined`.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNybz/1/)

but if you test this without `true` or `false`, it will evaluate `true` or `false`:

```
function fn2(){
    return;
}

if (!fn2()){
    alert("not fn2"); //we hit this
}
```

At [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNybz/4/)

http://jsfiddle.net/TNybz/2/

Comment: That's interesting.  I also added function fn3(){} and it alerted as well. But apparently, best practice is to explicitly say return false.

Answer (score 5):

No, I do not think so. False is usually returned to indicate that the specified action the function is supposed to do has failed. So that the calling function can check if the function succeeded.

Return is just a  way to manipulate programming flow.

Answer (score 5):

It's returning `undefined` it's commonly used to break execution of the following lines in the function

Answer (score 3):

No.

Test it in firebug console (or wherever) -

```
alert((function(){return;})() == false); //alerts false.

alert((function(){return false;})() == false); //alerts true.

alert((function(){return;})()); //alerts undefined
```

Note that if you (even implicitly) cast undefined to boolean, such as in if statement, it will evaluate to false.

Related interesting read [here](http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls%3a_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN) and [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Essential_Javascript_--_A_Javascript_Tutorial)

Comment: I have firebug installed and use it to inspect things, but have never used it as a kind of javascript notepad.  How do I copy/paste into firebug?

Comment: @cf_PhilipSenn - Open firebug, go to console. There you will either see a "command line" (marked by >>>) or if you have "show large command line" console option set, you will see it as a text area in the right side (in console tab). Paste one of the statements above and hit Enter (for small command line) or click on Run (large command line)

Answer (score 2):

Its undefined

```
console.log((function(){return ;})())
```

And yes in javaScript return is such a powerful stuff if used nicely in patters. You can return all the way to [] array, {} object to functions too.

Returning "this" you can go ahead and get implementation of class based objects and prototype inheritance and all.