# Any difference between return vs return 0 in C

Tags: c

I have heard people saying the return type of `main` is strictly `int`

```
 int main(){
     printf("hello world");
     return 0; // returning 0 to main indicates successful execution
 }
```

Instead I tried simply `return`.

```
 int main(){
     printf("hello world");
     return; // 
 }
```

It does not raise any warning or error. I wonder does it return `0` or some undefined value like in JavaScript?

I was reading this question [return false the same as return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596404/return-false-the-same-as-return) that says `return` and `return false` both are different in JavaScript. Is it the same in C?

Comment: "*It does not raise any warning or error*" but it may not be portable. It is implementation dependent.

Comment: It is not implementation dependent, in the code snippet shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard explicitly states as a constraint:

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function
>   whose return type is void. A return statement without an expression
>   shall only appear in a function whose return type is void.

and `main` is no exception from that. So no this is not allowed by the standard.

What is allowed by the standard as an exception for `main` compared to other functions is that control may drop out of `main` at the end without having an explicit `return` statement. But these two things are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

**(NOTE: This answer is incorrect. See [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19402702/15168).)**

The C standard specifies that, *in the `main()` function*, <s>an empty return, or</s> falling off the end, is the same as `return 0`. For all other functions, it's not gonna work.

Comment: I don't think that the term "return from the initial call to the main function" implies an explicit `return` statement without expression is allowed.

Comment: Hm, you may be right. It's not completely clear to me whether the special-casing of `main` trumps the special casing of `return` without a value, but the latter doesn't seem to have much wiggle room.

Comment: After looking into the standard, I think this answer is simply wrong with respect to a `return` without expression. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Ben, perhaps you could delete you answer?  This might encourage the questioner to accept the other answer.