# How do I stop a program if the user gets something wrong?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program where the user enters how much money he has and if it's under 50 it would say"

```
Sorry not Enough
```

and I want the program to end there.

Here is the code I have written:

```
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
}
cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
int a = 50;
int b = 200;
```

of course this is not the entire code I wrote. If the person wrote a number less than 50, how do I make the code stop?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean *exit* the program? *Return* from the `main` function?

Comment: You should use if else statement for this.

Comment: Do you want a full stop? Then just write `exit(0);` in the `if` block.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah something like that

Comment: with so scarce code, it is difficult to help

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `return` after:

```
cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
```

This will stop the code.

Comment: Do I have to write "return 0;"?

Comment: Yes, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402295/any-difference-between-return-vs-return-0-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Your program ends when you `return` from `main()`, so you should arrange for that to happen.

Alternatively you *could* call `exit()`, but that's a bad idea since destructors won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code like this:

```
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
}
else {
   cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
   // Operations you want to perform 
}
```

Comment: @MiguelNunez: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Using a `return` statement or the `exit()` function in C++ will exit the program. Your code would look like:

```
int main()
{
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
    return 0;
}
cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
int a = 50;
int b = 200;
}
```

Conversely, with exit() function, it would look like:

```
#include<stdlib.h> //For exit function
int main()
{
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
int a = 50;
int b = 200;
}
```

Comment: `return EXIT_FAILURE;`, maybe.

Comment: or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Comment: I changed it to `return 0;`. Does that indicate success?

Comment: Whether the program returns with success or failure depends on whether the exit status is used to control something in the executing environment.

Comment: Yes, `return 0;` is the same as `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.