# JavaScript prototype to empty variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using JavaScript, is it possible to use prototype to add a method to a variable that hasn't been given a value yet.

For example, I can do this:

```
var foo = "bar";

String.prototype.doTheFoo = function(){
  console.log("foo is better than you");
};

foo.doTheFoo();
```

This gives all strings the method doTheFoo();

Is it possible to some how do the same, however with something that hasn't been given a value?

```
var foo;

(????).prototype.doTheFoo = function()...
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Prototyped methods go on object constructors. The default value of `var foo` is `undefined`, which does not have a constructor.

You can add the method to all objects by extending `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'doTheFoo', {
    value: function() { alert('foo'); }
});
```

Now any value that has an object wrapper can use the method.

Notice that I used `Object.defineProperty` for the assignment. This is only available in ES5 compliant implementations. It makes the property non-enumerable, so it is relatively safe.

---

Since you seem to want this to work on an `undefined` value in lieu of a `typeof` test, consider the fact that ***`typeof` is never needed for to test for `undefined`***.

If this is what you've been told, you've been deceived. Many people think this, merely because that's what they've always been told. It is not true.

The following test is a perfectly safe test for `undefined`...

```
if (foo === undefined) {
```

...as long as you heed the following...

1. ***Never*** shadow or define `window.undefined` with a different value
2. ***Never*** use any code that violates the #1
3. ***Never*** try to get the value of an *undeclared* variable

Be responsible to maintain an uncorrupted environment *(a very simple task)*, and you'll have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put gas in a car you don't have yet?  Of course not; you can't attach something to nothing.

Likewise, you can't attach a method to an empty variable; there's nothing (and therefore no `prototype` to attach to).

Technically speaking, a declared but unassigned variable is *undefined*, which is a special primitive value type.  Primitives have no properties, so you can't attach any methods to it.

You *could* add something to `Object`'s `prototype` (from which everything else inherits), so that when you do assign some value to a variable, it will have that method, **but this is a very, *very* bad idea.**

Comment: The only reason I ask was to see if I could somehow create a method called `exists()` so instead of having to do if typeof checks I can just go `if varname.exists` to check if given a value or null :)

Comment: @tehlulz: You don't have to use `typeof` checks. Just check for the default `undefined` value. If you want to test for `null` and `undefined`, do `if (varname == null)`, which tests for both.

Comment: You can't invoke a method on an undefined identifier -- it's a `ReferenceError`.  Attempting to do so throws an exception well before the stage where JS would walk the prototype chain to find your method.  Unfortunately, you're stuck with `typeof`.

Comment: @amnotiam: You do indeed need `typeof` checks if you can't be sure the variable has been declared.  Dereferencing an undeclared identifier throws a `ReferenceError`.  (Try it now -- pop open a console and type `if (foo) {}`)  Also, remember that [`undefined` isn't necessarily that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4226440/201952).

Comment: @josh3736: It is never needed. If the variable is local *(your code)*, you should not be trying to reference an undeclared variable. If the variable is global, and you can't be certain of its declaration, check for it as a property of the global object.

Comment: ...and if `undefined` has been shadowed/redefined, the ***only*** solution is to remove the offending code, ***not*** to accommodate the offending code.

Comment: @amnotiam, that's all a nice principled stand, but sometimes in the real world, you just have to deal with other people's code and hostile environments.  You're right that locally you don't need `typeof` since JavaScript is statically scoped.  (In fact, it's [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).)  However, there are times you just can't be 100% certain; and if you're developing a library that other people will use, it's best to assume the worst.  I'd rather my library just work even if someone does redefine `undefined`.

Comment: @josh3736: If you're developing a library for public use, your internal code should be in a closure anyway where a safe `undefined` is declared. Once that is done, a corrupted global is irrelevant. If you've imported some other code that corrupts `undefined`, consider that to be a litmus test for the code quality, and remove it.